# Storing a c# DateTimeOffset value in a SQL Server 2005 database

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, datetimeoffset

I want to store a a c# DateTimeOffset value in a SQL Server 2005 database.

Sql 2008 has this as a built-in-type, but SQL Server 2005 does not.

The DateTimeOffset structure has a DateTime value which I store as DateTime, an an Offset property (of type TimeSpan). Since this is the time zone relative to UTC, presumably it is usually at a whole number of hours or half-hours.

Suggestions on how best to store this in a SQL Server 2005 database?

Comment: Related question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532729/daylight-saving-time-and-timezone-best-practices

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not a good idea to assume that an offset is a number of hours or half-hours - there are certainly quarter-hour timezones around.

Using milliseconds for the offset is probably the most flexible, but I'd argue that minutes is a lot easier to read. If you're ever going to look at the "raw" data in the database, it's easier to understand value 60 = 1 hour than 3600000. I can't imagine you really needing fractions of minutes as the offset.

Answer (score 4):

Normalize all DateTimeOffsets to a common offset, preferably UTC.  Then just store the DateTime as usual.  Upon extraction restore the offset, which should be a constant.  This doesn't retain the originating offset but the offset is ambiguous to a timezone anyway.

If you actually need to know the date/time origin, then you'd need to store some timezone information.  This is because a simple offset can't unambiguously represent the origin of a time.  Please see (the somewhat confusing) MSDN documentation about [Choosing Between DateTime, DateTimeOffset, and TimeZoneInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384267.aspx).

Comment: Agreed - store dates as UTC and only worry about timezones and DST offsets at the moment of presentation to the user.

Comment: I disagree. The DateTimeOffset structure (in C# and SQL 2008) stores time as either UTC or local time + offset. Storing a UTC time + offset would reverse that relationship and only cause confusion.

Answer (score 1):

store the datetime as datetime and the offset as milliseconds (bigint)